# Generate Java Swing UI Touch Screen Interaction Heat Maps

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, touch, heatmap

I have created an experiment to evaluate various cursors( [Bubble Cursor](http://ieor.berkeley.edu/~anandk/bubbleCursor.html), [Area Cursor](http://faculty.washington.edu/wobbrock/pubs/uist-10.pdf)). Although I have generated the response time and accuracy for each interaction I was interested in knowing user touch patterns and visualize it in heat maps. I could find several API's for [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425017/how-to-achieve-density-heat-map-effect-in-ios-iphone-ipad), [javascript](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/), etc. Since Java Swing package isn't meant to be for touch screen, I couldn't find a way to generate them. Only way I could thing of is to find the touch point pixels and then use some visual tools to generate heatmaps in x-y plane. Any better solution is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901472/230513), I added the following code to the mouse handler and dragged the mouse diagonally across the image to get the effect pictured below. For simplicity, I used `darker()` on each pass, but a transformation in HSB space may also be appealing, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875534/230513).

```
@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    …
    Color color = new Color(img.getRGB(x, y));
    int c = color.darker().getRGB();
    img.setRGB(x, y, c);
    repaint();
    …
}
```

[image]

Alternatively, look at using [`JFreeChart`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info) with an `XYBubbleRenderer` or an `XYShapeRenderer`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19538120/230513). Add a `ChartMouseListener` to highlight the selected bubble, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7999587/230513) for a `StackedXYBarRenderer`.

[image]

Also consider the [prefuse](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/prefuse/info) visualization library.  As the mouse moves over each entry in `prefuse.demos.Congress`,  illustrated below, the highlight, tooltip and detail text change.

[image]

Comment: Bubblechart was a good resource. Now I could just create bubble corresponding to X,Y coordinates and adjust the size of bubble to the value of touch time.

Comment: All three approaches use the same underlying mechanism; I've cited them in (roughly) increasing order of complexity; use `javax.swing.Timer` to pace the animation, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8616169/230513).